# Build Cordova project on Windows

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I am trying to build a Cordova project on Windows using the steps I was given by the team who developed it.

- Install Bower, Cordova CLI, Grunt CLI, SASS/Compass/sass-globbing gems
- `grunt build`
- `cordova platforms add android`

Then trying to run `grunt emulate android` but getting an error. I have the Android SDK installed and can fire up an emulator but I'm getting the following when trying to run that command:

```
Warning: Task "android" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Cordova/PhoneGap development and all this interplay between packages is daunting.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should run

`cordova run android` or `grunt emulate:android`

First part with cordova CLI should run all the time, and no need to use Grunt to launch application, if all assets are prepared.

Grunt part is just a guess work based on how I would organize `Gruntfile.js` and I could be wrong here. Without seeing more details, hard to tell you more.

Comment: @codevision Thanks, that command actually did work to launch the app in the emulator. It's launching a black screen, so I just have to troubleshoot whether that's a problem with the code.